# usb_cam Exit code -11

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm really new in ROS(I started a year ago, though), and I have a question using usb_cam package.

I'm working on using **purethermal1** with **Flir Lepton 2.5**,

and launched usb_cam-test.launch file, but the process is failed with **exit code -11**.

There're some WARNINGS, but I think nothing is related to process failing.

I dont know what causes exit code -11, so I ask question here.

But it's OK when I try same process with logitech webcam.

So, my question is,

**Do you guys have recommanded ROS Package to watch thermal cam?**

I'm using **UBUNTU 16.04, ROS Kinetic**

I insists ros because we need raw data in ros message to another processing procedure.

I hope cool advice, thx.

And really sorry for my short English.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279567/usb_cam-exit-code--11/) by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind with this question. I found myself.

Just using **usb_cam** package, which is already included ROS system.

The important points are **pixel format** and **width, height**.

In purethermal1, **pixel format is uyvy, 80 x 60 resolutions.**

Just modify that parameter in launch file.

and do the roslaunch:

**sudo chmod +x /dev/video0**

**roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch**

And everything works fine.

---

Originally posted by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) with karma: 41 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0